# ExtJS GridPanel with radiobutton on the columns

Tags: javascript, extjs, radio-button, extjs6, gridpanel

So i have an usual grid, with some columns:

```
                  {
                        xtype          : 'gridpanel',
                        mode           : "MULTI",
                        region         : 'center',
                        title          : "grid",
                        id             : 'datagridResult',  
                        margin         : '10 5 5 5',

                    columns : [
                               {
                                   xtype    : 'gridcolumn',
                                   dataIndex: 'TEST',
                                   flex     : 0.25
                               },   
                               {
                                   xtype    : 'gridcolumn',
                                   dataIndex: 'Test2'
                                   flex     : 2
                               },   
                               //...
```

What i want is to add 3 more columns which are radiobuttons (one button per column). I tried something like this:

```
                             {
                                   xtype    : 'gridcolumn',
                                   text     : "FOR"
                                   dataIndex: 'for',
                                   flex     : 1,
                                   editor: { 
                                        xtype     : 'radiofield',
                                        name      : 'Regex',
                                        inputValue: 'Checked'
                                    },
                               }
```

And it doesn't work. So i am here to ask any sugestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And it doesn't work. So i am here to ask any sugestions

In ExtJS have xtype :['widgetcolumn'](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html). 
A widget column is configured with a widget config object which specifies an xtype to indicate which type of Widget or Component belongs in the cells of this column.

I have created an [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27os) demo. It will show how is working. Hope this will help you.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', {
        name: 'checked',
        type: 'boolean',
        defaultValue: true
    }],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224'
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234'
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244'
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        text: 'Status',
        width: 150,
        xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'checked',
        onWidgetAttach: function (column, widget, record) {
            widget.down(`[inputValue=${record.get('checked')}]`).setValue(true);
        },
        widget: {
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'Yes',
                inputValue: true
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'No',
                inputValue: false
            }]
        }
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, precisly what i wanted